# After inserting Korean characters in MySQL via HTML and PHP character appear like &#50612;

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, encoding

thanks in advance .

After inserting Korean characters in **MySQL** via **HTML** FORM and **PHP**, character appear like **&# 50612;**.

i worked with HTML entity's but wont work for me, this is my form its simple
[image: this is my form its simple .]

this i the data i've inserted in MYSQL the **Blue** one i've inserted it manually and the **Red** one i've inserted it with my HTML form and PHP .

[image]

Comment: if you log in the mysql console and run a select for that record with korean characters, is it displayed corectly ?

Comment: no the one i've inserted with form displayed like that :
&#50612;&#46160;&#50892;&#51256; &#44032; &#45236;

Comment: well, clearly somewhere in your form validation you're encoding the characters and turning them into entities. Please show your form validation code (the PHP code that is).

Comment: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8');

$title =    $_GET['title'];
$content =    $_GET['content'];
$lang =    $_GET['lang'];
$id_singer =   $_GET['id_singer'];


    $connection = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$username) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Song(Title,Content,lang,id_singer)       values('$title',N'$content','$lang','$id_singer') ";

Comment: If you are using, `json_encode`, be sure to add the second argument that avoids escaping unicode into html entities.